# HashTable containsValue not working properly

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a huge float array and I have to remove duplicates from it. I tried to create an HashTable to populate with unique values and pass it back to another array and return it. The problem is in containsValue method, which always returns false, so all points are added in the HashTable.

```
private float[] removeDuplicates1(float[] input){
    Hashtable<Integer, float[]> h= new Hashtable<>();
    for(int i=0; i<input.length/3; ++i) {
        float[] pt= new float[]{input[i * 3], input[i * 3 + 1], input[i * 3 + 2]};
        Log.i(TAG, Float.toString(pt[0]) + " " +Float.toString(pt[1]) + " " +Float.toString(pt[2]));  //ok
        Log.i(TAG, Boolean.toString(h.containsValue(pt)));      //always false !?
        if(!(h.containsValue(pt))){
            h.put(i,pt);
            Log.i(TAG, "added");
        }
        else Log.i(TAG, "NOT added");
    }
    float[] whitelist = new float[h.size()*3];
    int a=0;
    for(int j=0; j<h.size(); j++){
        float[] f= h.get(j);
        whitelist[a]= f[0];
        whitelist[a+1]= f[1];
        whitelist[a+2]= f[2];
        a=a+3;
    }
    return whitelist;
}
```

I really appreciate ay help.

Comment: You're asking whether one array is equal to another one, basically. That is *never* going to be true - arrays don't override `equals`. It looks like your input is really a collection of triples - it sounds like you should construct a class with three `float` fields (we can't really tell what they're meant to mean) which overrides `equals` appropriately. Also note that `Hashtable.containsValue` is basically an O(n) lookup - that's a really bad choice to de-dupe data.

Comment: containsValue uses equals method to compare and two arrays are never equal.

Comment: Don't forget to override `hashCode()` too, since you want to use a HashTable it only compares Objects with the same hashcode. Simpliest hashCode would be in your case the length of the arry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h.containsValue(pt)` compares the addresses of the arrays, not their contents, when looking for a match.

To achieve what you want, you can write a wrapper class to be used as values in the map, and override `equals` and `hashcode` for it.

Comment: Ok, I understand I have to do a wrapper object class for the float[] Point, but I don't understand what hashcode is and how does it work. Can u provide me an example of that?

Comment: the `hashcode` contract is described in the javadoc of class Object:  
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()  
Part of that contact is: "•If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result", which is why you should always override it when you override `equals`.  
Eclipse has an option for generating both based on the Class's members.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
private float[] removeDuplicates1(float[] input){
    Hashtable<Integer, Point> h= new Hashtable<>();
    int hn=0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length/3; ++i) {
        Point pt= new Point(input[i * 3], input[i * 3 + 1], input[i * 3 + 2]);
        Log.i(TAG, Float.toString(pt.x) + " " +Float.toString(pt.y) + " " +Float.toString(pt.z));
        Log.i(TAG, Boolean.toString(h.containsValue(pt)));
        if(!(h.containsValue(pt))){
            h.put(hn,pt);
            hn++;
            Log.i(TAG, "added");
        }
        else Log.i(TAG, "NOT added");
    }
    float[] whitelist = new float[h.size()*3];
    int a=0;
    for(int j=0; j<h.size(); ++j){
        Point p = new Point(h.get(j));
        whitelist[a] = p.x;
        whitelist[a + 1] = p.y;
        whitelist[a + 2] = p.z;
        a = a + 3;
    }
    return whitelist;
}
```

Wrapper

```
public class Point {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;

    public Point(float x, float y, float z){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }

    public Point(Point p){
        this.x=p.x;
        this.y=p.y;
        this.z=p.z;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        final Point p = (Point) o;
        if((p.x==this.x) && (p.y==this.y) && (p.z==this.z)) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + Float.floatToIntBits(this.x);
        hash = 53 * hash + Float.floatToIntBits(this.y);
        hash = 53 * hash + Float.floatToIntBits(this.z);
        return hash;
    }
}
```